# WPF: Using .ico files as images for a toolbar? Or need to convert to XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I know it's recommended to convert images to XAML as they become blurred when changing the dpi.

What about standard ICO files which actually are really BMP files?

I need to use these in a toolbar. Do I need to convert all to XAML?

Is there a better way?

What about a similar feature in HTML called sprites where it's one big image but you get items via positions?

Comment: I've always had the best luck extracting the resolution icon (keeping in mind that .ico files can have multiple resolutions in one file) from the .ico file and converting that to something like a .png or .gif

Comment: Windows .ico files are not .bmp files. They contain multiple images, masks, a directory of sizes, colour depths etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essencially you work with static images when no scaling is needed, and you work with Vector Images when you want to perform all sorts of scaling. This is the rule of thumb for most WPF and Silverlight applications.

However you can't directly convert a static image to a Vector Image (what you call XAML), and most times it will require a designer to do some work on the Vector Image.

Working with vector images makes the rendering process heavier, the more vectors, the slower the rendering pass. It also makes it slower to instanciate a particular Visual Tree, when you add it to something already on screen. This can be overcome if you call RenderToBitmap and cache the sizes of the Vector Images you want to use, but this requires aditional custom code.

Working with static images allows for much faster renders. However upsizing will cause pixelization and downsizing may cause artifacts on the image. When you work with static images PNG is considered to be the prefered format, you have full control over the compression, you have alpha key and it's an indexed format which makes it fairly small in size.

Comment: Thanks David! So the rule of thumb... how do i know its going to scale? take an example.. a login screen i want to place at the left of the username / password textbox a picture about 48x48 of a LOCK / KEY. Is this going to scale if the DPI increase, i presume EVERYTHING will scale if the dpi increases.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Ideally you want everything to be vector in WPF/Silverlight. You can poke me if you want for a good icon library already converted to XAML Usercontrols. If you encounter performance issues, and this will be mainly from constructing the pages, you start writing custom code to RenderBitmap and cache local pre-rendered versions of what you're showing.

Answer (score 0):

I always convert all images to `XAML` where it's possible. I think it's good rule.